# Python Pandas Column Value Increment Counter for Unique Values

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a series like (assume this is a dataframe with many columns, but I only care about `df["Key"]` right now) :

```
Key
----
1234
1234
1234
5678
6789
7890
7890
6789
2345
```

How do I create a new column called "Counter" that increments matching values in `"Key"` ?, like the following :

```
Key     Counter
----    -------
1234       1
1234       2
1234       3
5678       1
6789       1
7890       1
7890       2
6789       2
2345       1
```

I don't want a summary of the total count of each unique value...I know that you can get a value of unique counts by doing something like `df["Key"].value_counts()` or `df.groupby('Key').count()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use pd groupby cumcount:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html

which maps to 0-n, so optionally add 1 to the result:

```
out = df.groupby('Key').cumcount() + 1
```

Comment: Thank you! I was stuck on this and have never used `cumcount()` before. This is a great introduction to the usefulness of it.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
df["Counter"] = df.groupby("Key").cumcount().reset_index(drop=True) + 1
```

this will produce your expected result:

```
    Key  Counter
0  1234        1
1  1234        2
2  1234        3
3  5678        1
4  6789        1
5  7890        1
6  7890        2
7  6789        2
8  2345        1
```